# How do I check if the socket is still connected?

Tags: python, sockets

```
import socket

ip = '127.1.0.0'
port = 2400

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((ip, port))

clientsocket, address = s.accept()

while True:
    s.listen(10)

    print(f'{address[0]}:{address[1]}')

    msg = clientsocket.recv(8196)
    print(msg.decode(), "\n")

    time.sleep(.05)
```

This is my server. Whenever I shut down the client server, the while loop continues to print the address and port continuously until I terminate the program. How do I check if the client is still connected, and if not, then close it. I have tried the try and except, and put s.send(bytes()) in the try, and break in the except, but every time I sent a message to the server from the client, it would break the while loop. I am also new to socket programming, so it probably is a little messy.

Comment: `recv()` returns `""` if the peer has disconnected. You need to test for this. "Every time I sent a message to the server from the client, it would break the while loop": that's one way you can tell, but you don't want to gussy up your application protocol with pings.

Comment: NB 1. `s.listen()` should be up ahead of the loop, and conversely `s.accept()` should be inside it, with another inner loop or thread to handle the I/O on the accepted client. 2. The `sleep()` is literally a waste of time. You don't need it. `recv()` will block until something happens on the socket.

Answer (score 0):

When the other side disconnected the socket, `recv` returns 0 bytes (empty string).

Note that this is the *only* time when `recv` returns 0 bytes. Otherwise, it keeps waiting until there are some bytes. So you know that if it receives 0 bytes then the other computer disconnected.

Note: in old versions of Python 2, that means recv returns `""`. In Python 3 it returns `b""`. I like to write `if len(msg) == 0:` to cover both cases, but assuming you're using Python 3, `if msg == b"":` is also fine

Comment: Simply `if not msg:` will suffice. Any non-empty string (even if it is all null bytes) will be considered a truthy value.